# How many positive divisors of 2000?

Tags: combinatorics, divisibility

I thought that the number of divisors of a number was the product of the indices in its factorisation, plus $2$ (for 1 and the number itself). For instance, $2000=2^{4} \cdot 5^{3}$, so it would have $4 \cdot 3 + 2 = 14$ divisors.

Apparently, however, $2000$ actually has $20$ divisors. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Solve a simpler problem. How many divisors are there of 36? That's two squared times three squared. Your theory is that for some reason you multiply the exponents and add two, giving 6.  But the divisors of 36 are 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9, 12, 18, 36, which is nine divisors.  Where did the reasoning go wrong? **By enumerating the cases your technique counts you can see which three you missed and why**.

Comment: $\sigma_0(2000)$, where $\sigma_0(n)$ is the number of divisors of n.

Comment: @EricLippert An even simpler argument is that $2000=2^43^05^3$, so by OP's argument the number of divisors should be $4*0*3=0$.

Comment: @Acccumulation Yes, but how does that help OP find $\sigma_0(2000)$?

Comment: @Teepeemm It was a bit tongue in cheek, but seriously, type "sigma number of divisors" into Google and see how long it takes to find the formula. In this day and age, "The function to find the number of divisors is called $\sigma_0$" is plenty of information to someone willing to do even the slightest internet search.

Comment: @Acccumulation "number of divisors" also returns a formula, and doesn't require anyone to know that $\sigma$ is called "sigma".  But if we're going by that criteria, then we should be complaining that OP didn't do a Google search, not saying that OP needed to know that $\sigma$ is "sigma" and should have had that with their Google search.

Answer (score 19):

The factors are of the form of $2^x\cdot 5^y$ where $x$ takes value from $0$ to $4$ and $y$ takes values from $0$ to $3$.

Hence there is a total of $(4+1)(3+1)=20$ factors.

Your method miss out number such as $5^y, y>0; 4^x, x>0$ and double counted $2000$.

Answer (score 6):

A divisor of $2^4\,5^3$ has the prime decomposition $2^i\,5^j$, where $\;0\le i\le 4$ ($5$ possibilities) and $0\le j\le3$ ($4$ possibilities). Combining these possibilities, this make $5\cdot 4$ divisors in all.

More generally, given the prime decomposition of a number $n$, the number of its positive divisors is the product of the exponents plus $1$  of its prime factors.

Answer (score 5):

You take $2$ to any power between $0$ and $4$, and $3$ with any power between $0$ and $3$, hence $5\times4$ combinations.

---

You forgot the options such that one exponent is zero, $2,4,8,16$ and $5,25,125$, and you counted $2^4\cdot5^3=2000$ twice. Hence, $14-1+4+3=20$.

Answer (score 2):

Brute force: \begin{array}{c|cccc}1&2&4&8&16\\\hline5&10&20&40&80\\25&50&100&200&400\\125&250&500&1000&2000\end{array} In general, if $n=\prod_i p_i^{a_i}$ then the number of divisors is $\tau(n)=\prod_i(a_i+1)$.

Comment: Maybe a more intuitive way to arrange the divisors is \begin{array}{ccccc}1&2&4&8&16\\5&10&20&40&80\\25&50&100&200&400\\125&250&500&1000&2000\end{array}

Answer (score 1):

Lets look at any natural number and it's positive divisors.

Every number $n$ greater than $1$ can be represented uniquely in a form of
$$n = (p_1)^{i_1}\cdot(p_2)^{i_2}\cdot\ldots\cdot(p_m)^{i_m}=\prod_{1\leq l \leq m} (p_l)^{i_l}$$
where $p_l$ is a strictly growing sequence of prime numbers.

Now any number that is in a form
$$d = (p_1)^{j_1}\cdot(p_2)^{j_2}\cdot\ldots\cdot(p_m)^{j_m}=\prod_{1\leq l \leq m}(p_l)^{j_l}, \text{where } \forall_{1\leq l\leq m} 0\leq j_l \leq i_l$$
is a divisor of $n$ and all divisors of $n$ are exactly in that form. The proof is obvious so let me skip it.

In other words we have $l$ sets of natural numbers from $0$ to $i_l$ so each of those sets has exactly $i_l+1$ elements. To create a divisor of $n$ we need to pick exactly one element from each of the sets. We can do that in 
$$\sigma=\prod_{1\leq l\leq m}(i_l+1) = (i_1+1)\cdot(i_2+1)\cdot\ldots\cdot(i_m+1)$$
So $\sigma$ is your total number of unique positive divisors of $n$.

In your case
$$2000=2^4\cdot5^3$$
hence
$$m=2$$
$$p_1=2$$
$$p_2=5$$
$$i_1=4$$
$$i_2=3$$
$$\sigma = (4+1)\cdot(3+1)=5\cdot 4 = 20$$

> What am I doing wrong

Well, the answer is actually here

> I thought that the number of divisors of a number was the product of the indices in its factorisation, plus 2 (for 1 and the number itself)

With this you ignore the possibility of entirely dropping $l\text{-th}$ prime number when creating your divisors (i.e. having $j_l=0$ for any $l$).